# Why laptop battery so small and UPS bigger and heavier but can only hold lesser powering duration?

Tags: battery, ups

My friend asked this earlier today, facts that most:

- laptop battery are smaller
- laptop battery are lighter in weight
- laptop battery can give more time without plugging to power outlet
- laptop power usage are lower power consumption
- UPS doesn't only contain battery but also stabilizer

is the large and heavy parts on the UPS is the non-battery components? or laptop and UPS has different battery material?

Comment: Since when does a UPS not contain a batter?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: There are some UPS that doesn't contain battery, but maybe you misread my statement.

Comment: If a UPS doesn't contain a battery then it isn't a UPS, most UPS, they also use a different type of battery.

Comment: A sports car has a much smaller engine than a bus, but a sports car has better acceleration and can go faster.  Why?  Your phone has a much smaller battery than your laptop but has longer run time.  Why?  The comparison is similar.

Comment: @Ramhound Is a backup generator more or less an uninterruptable power supply compared to a battery-backed UPS?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - What?  A backup generator is just that a generator that will take over if the main generator ( your power company ) connection is shut off ( down power line ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heavy parts are indeed the batteries.

It is not so much a different material as it is a different type of voltage/Amperage output.  A laptop battery only puts out DC voltage and it is only a specified voltage/amperage that the laptop needs to run.

On a UPS, the batteries have to convert the DC voltage to AC voltage at 120V (US) therefore requiring more AMPs to convert.  Think of the UPS as a temporary plug in at your house.

When you plug in your laptop at your house, you are converting AC to a lower DC which takes less energy.  When you use your UPS, you take DC and raise it to AC which uses far more energy.

Amperage and Wattage is the key.  The more amps, the faster the batteries discharge  which is why UPS's don't last a long time without power.

As a side note, your laptop charger (AC) uses much more power that your laptop battery (DC).

Answer (score -1):

Your question contains different parts.

- UPS and battery are different components. The main purpose of UPS is
  to provide Uninterrupted Power by converting Battery's DC current into AC Current. See [UPS and it's
  functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply)
- Mostly, Lead Acid battery is used along with UPS to provide Power
  Supply. See [Automotive Battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_battery)
- On the other, Laptops, Mobiles and other such electronic devices uses
  Lithium-Ion battery.
- Lastly, the power usage of Laptop are too low as compare to UPS. Since UPS are meant to be used in Homes, Offices to provide temporary Power for all the Electrical devices. While Laptop battery just need to provide power to the hardware components in Laptop which uses less power than electrical devices in homes/offices

Comment: *"The main purpose of UPS is to convert DC current ..."*   -- You are confusing the *means* to accomplish a function/purpose with its actual *purpose* (i.e. to provide equivalent AC line power).

Comment: @sawdust edited!

Comment: A backup generator is also a UPS (although one that usually takes a little longer to start providing useful power). However, a generator does not use any battery to do so, with the possible exception of the starter which is merely incidental. A generator (general term) also doesn't produce DC, it produces (commonly quite dirty) AC.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Kindly read OP's question again, by term UPS, he meant the typical UPS device used in offices/home etc, not generator. I wrote the answer accordingly

Comment: Actually, the abbreviation UPS in this context simply means [Uninterruptible Power Supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply). This can be achieved in a number of different ways, the two main ones being battery- and generator-backed. So the "main purpose" of a UPS is to provide uninterrupted, stable power in the face of unstable or nonexistent mains power. How this is *achieved* is secondary to the purpose of a UPS. The way you have phrased it makes it sound like the two are equally important, which was the point of my comment.